# Does changing the width property effect the grid text overflow?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

I have a html document, and  inside I have an element, lets call it `myElement` now `myElement`has `display: grid` set. `myElement` also has `width: 60%`, this width property seems to be changing how the text overflow is working on its child grid  elements - the text is going out of the grid's 60% width. Is there a workaround so that the text overflow will still work properly or do I just have to deal with the grid being 100% of its space?

Here is the code snippet(not great representation)

```css
#events-grid {
    background-color: #14ffec;
    display: grid;
    font-size: 20px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    margin: 0 20%;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 60%;
}

.event {
     grid-column: 1/3;
 }

.dates {
     grid-column: 3/4;
}

.summary-event {
    grid-column: 4/9;
}

.source-event {
     grid-column: 9/11;
}
```

```html
<div id="events-grid">
    <span class="event">Random Event</span>
    <span class="dates">Random Date</span>
    <span class="summary-event">Random text about the event that means nothing</span>
    <span class="source-event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
```

This is the picture (the blue is the 60% grid the gray is the background, and the text is just random - replacing a link)

[image]

I think it has to do with there being no spaces, because when I add spaces (to the source-event) it overflows perfectly:

[image]

Comment: Please look at: [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AndyHoffman What about it, what part did I get wrong, I'm trying to start to ask better questions so all of your help is appreciated.

Comment: don't descirbe code, show us the code so we can see the issue ... not all of us will understand english the same way but we will all understand the code the same way

Comment: I'm glad you included some `CSS`, but it would be more helpful to include a fully testable example with the `HTML` there as well. That way, we can tinker and view the code in a web inspector's developer tools.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Is that better?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry I meant to ask you, is that better?

Comment: yes better and you issue seems related to word breaking, not grid specifically .. read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: What are your current questions given the answers we've provided?

Comment: @AndyHoffman After the answer that I found, none

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is add `word-break: break-all` to the `.summary-event`. Things can still get tight for other children, so you'll probably want to add some new grid rules (via `@media` query) when the screen passes a certain minimum threshold.

```css
#events-grid {
    background-color: #14ffec;
    display: grid;
    font-size: 20px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    margin: 0 20%;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 60%;
}

.event {
     grid-column: 1/3;
 }

.dates {
     grid-column: 3/4;
}

.summary-event {
    grid-column: 4/9;
    word-break: break-all;
    /* Option 2: word-wrap: anywhere; 
       Option 3: overflow-wrap: anywhere;
    */
}

.source-event {
     grid-column: 9/11;
}
```

```html
<div id="events-grid">
    <span class="event">Random Event</span>
    <span class="dates">Random Date</span>
    <span class="summary-event">Randomtextabouttheevent</span>
    <span class="source-event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what Andy has answered, this being an updated name but I too have found a solution, use `overflow-wrap` on the `#events-grid` and set the value to `overflow-wrap: break-word` As the [MDN Doc on overflow-wrap says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

> The overflow-wrap CSS property applies to inline elements, setting whether the browser should insert line breaks within an otherwise unbreakable string to prevent text from overflowing its line box.

Comment: `overflow-wrap: break-word` was not affecting the overflow, but `overflow-wrap: anywhere;` was.